"most" vs "the most"?
What is difference between this too?

What do you value most in you life?
What do you value the most in your life?

This is just an example, please provide a general answer to all similar constructiosn.

What is the difference between these two? None, really - but see this explanation.

@KateBunting I read whole of it. Which part of that page you are reffering to?

The explanation of when to use most and when to use the most!

@KateBunting thanks for your attempt to help. It doesn't look that page helps in answering the question.

The English language has rules, but perhaps not as strict as mathematics, physics, or programming. Language can be flexible. In this case, I think either of the superlative adverbs "most" or "the most" are allowed. With the article it's more emphatic and complete, while the plain "most" is more informal and casual, but the meaning is approximately the same.
